# Best way to do the login + authorization step on a OAuth2 flow (authorization_code grant)

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, oauth2-server

I'm implementing a OAuth2 server, and I have a doubt implementing the `authorization_code` grant type.

The standard says the authorization call should be a GET call with certain parameters (client_id, response_type, etc.), but it also says the first step has to be showing users a screen to login and to giver permission to the app to access their data.

I created a GET `/auth` call with the needed params that renders the screen. That form submits a POST `/auth` call with all the auth params + the username and password of the user.

Then, a middleware takes care of the authentication. If it fails, redirects the user to GET `/auth?[auth-params]&[error-message]` with an informative error message. If it's successful, then the `authorization_grant` proceeds, and if everything is correct I redirect the user to the `redirect_uri` with the authorization code, etc.

Is this the best way to implement this? I'm worried because:

- There's a POST version of the `/auth` call, and that's the call that actually does the authorization step.
- The standard suggests in case of a wrong user authentication, redirect to the `redirect_uri` with an `error=access_denied` query parameter, which I don't do (instead I redirect to the login page).

Any tips? Thank you.

PS: I think it's not relevant, but in any case, I'm implementing the server in node with ExpressJS.